# is it possible to Undo Texture Bake?

Tags: texture-painting

accidentally baked blank texture onto almost finished texture, bake mode: textures, Blender Renderer.

doing that to get bigger margins because texture brush's bleed is either too much or not enough. usually i save work in progress, but this was an easy piece, so i skipped that step. not a big deal in losing it, but i'm still curious if it's possible to Undo a bake like it's possible to undo brush strokes or most other actions

Comment: no, becaue there was nothing on it

Comment: If you didn't save the texture after you baked something undesired atop of it then just reload ot from the disk (Alt+R).

Comment: thing is, i didn't save the original texture even once, so there's nowhere to reload it from. but thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see. There's no way to undo that in this case unless undoing all the operations done in the node setup in order to bake what was on the first version of texture and bake then. However this is elongated version of simple answer "impossible to recover".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is No if you haven't already saved the last image to disk - a generated image texture that is being used to bake doesn't save automatically, so if you rest to bake again without saving previous results, it will not come back if you escape and undo.